# Delta Live Tables with EventHub

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-eventhub, delta-live-tables

I am trying to create streaming from eventhub using delta live tables, but I am having trouble installing the library . Is it possible to install maven library using Delta Live tables using sh /pip?

I would like to install
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/streaming-event-hubs

Comment: Currently clusters init scripts are not supported in delta live tables framework, I've add this comment to prevent other users from trying to solve this issue using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to use external connectors/Java libraries for Delta Live Tables. But for EventHubs there is a workaround - you can connect to EventHubs using the built-in Kafka connector - you just need to specify correct options as it's described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-spark-tutorial):

```py
@dlt.table
def eventhubs():
  readConnectionString="Endpoint=sb://<....>.windows.net/;?.."
  eh_sasl = f'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="{readConnectionString}";'
  kafka_options = {
     "kafka.bootstrap.servers": "<eh-ns-name>.servicebus.windows.net:9093",
     "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
     "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
     "kafka.request.timeout.ms": "60000",
     "kafka.session.timeout.ms": "30000",
     "startingOffsets": "earliest",
     "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": eh_sasl,
     "subscribe": "<topic-name>",
  }
  return spark.readStream.format("kafka") \ 
    .options(**kafka_options).load()
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up DLT pipeline using Azure event hub as source. Python for bronze table that reads from event hub. Sql for silver and gold tables:

In Event hub I am sending following json:
Make sure its not a list.

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz1"
}
```

Refer [Databricks Docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/event-hubs.html) for how to setup bronze layer in python.

**Python notebook**

```
import dlt
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Event Hubs configuration
EH_NAMESPACE                    = "xyz-eventhub1"
EH_NAME                         = "abc"

EH_CONN_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_NAME  = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
# SECRET_SCOPE                    = spark.conf.get("io.ingestion.eh.secretsScopeName")
EH_CONN_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_VALUE = "xyz="

EH_CONN_STR                     = f"Endpoint=sb://{EH_NAMESPACE}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={EH_CONN_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_NAME};SharedAccessKey={EH_CONN_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_VALUE}"

# Kafka Consumer configuration

KAFKA_OPTIONS = {
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers"  : f"{EH_NAMESPACE}.servicebus.windows.net:9093",
  "subscribe"                : EH_NAME,
  "kafka.sasl.mechanism"     : "PLAIN",
  "kafka.security.protocol"  : "SASL_SSL",
  "kafka.sasl.jaas.config"   : f"kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"{EH_CONN_STR}\";",
  "kafka.request.timeout.ms" : "60000",
  "kafka.session.timeout.ms" : "60000",
#   "maxOffsetsPerTrigger"     : spark.conf.get("iot.ingestion.spark.maxOffsetsPerTrigger"),
  "failOnDataLoss"           : "false",
  "startingOffsets"          : "earliest"
}

# PAYLOAD SCHEMA
payload_ddl = """id STRING, name STRING"""
payload_schema = T._parse_datatype_string(payload_ddl)

# Basic record parsing and adding ETL audit columns
def parse(df):
  print(df)
  return (df
    .withColumn("records", col("value").cast("string"))
    .withColumn("parsed_records", from_json(col("records"), payload_schema))
    # .withColumn("iot_event_timestamp", expr("cast(from_unixtime(parsed_records.timestamp / 1000) as timestamp)"))
    .withColumn("id", expr("parsed_records.id"))
    .withColumn("name", expr("parsed_records.name"))
    .withColumn("eh_enqueued_timestamp", expr("timestamp")) # when event was enqueued
    .withColumn("eh_enqueued_date", expr("to_date(timestamp)"))
    .withColumn("bronze_timestamp", col("current_timestamp"))
    .withColumn("bronze_uuid", expr("uuid()"))
    .drop("records", "value", "key")
  )

@dlt.create_table(
  comment="Raw events from kafka",
  table_properties={
    "quality": "bronze",
    "pipelines.reset.allowed": "false" # preserves the data in the delta table if you do full refresh
  },
  partition_cols=["eh_enqueued_date"]
)
@dlt.expect("valid_topic", "topic IS NOT NULL")
@dlt.expect("valid records", "parsed_records IS NOT NULL")
def kafka_bronze():
  return (
   spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .options(**KAFKA_OPTIONS)
    .load()
    .transform(parse)
  )
```

**Sql notebook**

Silver table

```
CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE kafka_cleaned(
  CONSTRAINT id_not_null EXPECT (id IS NOT NULL)
)
COMMENT "Cleaned kafka table"
TBLPROPERTIES ("companyPipeline.quality" = "silver")
AS
SELECT 
cast(id as int) as id,
name,
eh_enqueued_timestamp,
bronze_timestamp,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as silver_timestamp
FROM STREAM(LIVE.kafka_bronze)
```

Gold table

```
CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE kafka_gold
COMMENT "count of id per name"
TBLPROPERTIES ("companyPipeline.quality" = "gold")
AS
SELECT count(id) as count_id,
name,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as gold_timestamp 
FROM STREAM(LIVE.kafka_cleaned)
group by name
```

Use both these notebooks as source in DLT pipeline