# Databricks delta live tables from Azure data stream error - no tables were discovered

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, delta-live-tables

```
Attempted to update an empty pipeline. 
This error usually means that no tables were discovered in your specified Notebook libraries. 
Please verify that your Notebook libraries include table definitions.
```

DLT notebook code

```
%python

import dlt
@dlt.table
def kafka_raw():
    TOPIC = "<event_hub>"
    BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "<event_hub>.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
    EH_SASL = 'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://<event_hub>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<event_hub shared_access_policy primary_key>;";'

    return (
        spark.readStream.format("kafka")
        .option("subscribe", TOPIC)
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL)
        .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", "60000")
        .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "60000")
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load()
    )
```

Comment: Hmm, strange - do you see any warnings in the DLT event log in UI? Did you check that pipeline points to the correct path or branch in repo?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948856/3842788

Comment: your source code there doesn't match what you posted here. For example, `@dlt.create_table` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex Ott said check the source code path, whether it is taking the notebook having `dlt` definitions.

Below, is the normal notebook.

[image]

Then, I have given this notebook source code path to dlt pipeline.

[image]

After, running i got same error as you.
So, in **Source code** option give the correct notebook path having your `@dlt.table` decorator.

I changed to original notebook.

[image]

Then got output as expected.

Output:
[image]